# screwed up vim/gvim on ubuntu royally. how do I go back to square one

Tags: vim

I was trying to be super productive and tried to mimic my vim profile to others by grabbing their .vim file from github.  However, now vim and gvim are totally screwed up.  syntax highlighting doesn't work, snipMate doesn't work and many other things.

How can I go back to square one?  How do I completely remove vim and gvim and install from scratch.

```
sudo aptitude reinstall vim
```

does not help.

Answer (score 5):

The settings are stored in hidden files (which start with a dot), in your home directory.

Try removing these files:

- ~/.vimrc
- ~/.vim (directory)
- ~/.gvimrc

Comment: my set runtimepath shows : `~/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles, /usr/share/vim, /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after, ~/.vim/after`  shouldn't it be just one directory so everything is not scattered?  How can I chagne the runtimepath? I've already deleted `.vimrc`

Comment: You shouldn't even need to reinstall vim. I expect the vim files in /usr are all intended for distro-installed vim plugins. They shouldn't be causing any problems unless you deliberately installed vim extensions in them.

Comment: yeah I had deleted everything from /usr :(

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to (re)move your `~/.vim` directory (as well as `~/.vimrc` and `~/.gvimrc`)? That should take care of a lot of plugin functionality.

You most likely won't need to reinstall vim itself.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is delete your `~/.vimrc` file, and your `~/.vim` directory.

Comment: Works for vim 8.0